# Как найти конфиг, который использует iptables?

Tags: centos, iptables

На сайте настроен iptables. Разрешает коннект к порту 3306 только для одного IP. IP сменился, нужно открыть конфиг фаервола и сменить IP. 
Гуглю где находится его конфиг, гугль говорит, смотреть в /etc/sysconfig/iptables.old и в /etc/sysconfig/iptables-config.
Ага, думаю я, то что мне нужно, открываю эти конфиги, в них нет записи с нужным IP. Видимо iptables использует кастомный конфиг. Как узнать где он находится?

Answer (score 1):

текущий конфиг в rpm-дистрибутивах точно находится в /etc/sysconfig/iptables. В крайнем случае можно набрать команду iptables-save и сохранить в этом файле. Исправить и рестартовать iptables - способ лечения